# What topic should I subscribe to know when the drone is in "hover state"?

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, I'm trying to write a piece of code that waits for the drone to enter hover state and then take a picture from the drone's camera. I've manage to take the picture (by subscribing to ardrone/image_raw topic). I only need to know what topic should I subscribe so I can set up a subscriber and using a callback function I will be able to take pictures from the drone only when it is in hovering state.

Thank you in advance.

p.s:
I use tum_ardrone and ardrone_autonomy to communicate with the drone. I've also created a package that uses some opencv code to take the picture from the drone's camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201666/what-topic-should-i-subscribe-to-know-when-the-drone-is-in-%22hover-state%22?/) by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- ardrone/navdata topic.
  ======================

**Information received from the drone will be published to the ardrone/navdata topic. The message type is ardrone_autonomy::Navdata and contains the following information:**

- **header**: ROS message header
- **batteryPercent**: The remaining charge of the drone's battery (%)
- **state**: The Drone's current state: * 0: Unknown * 1: Inited * 2: Landed * 3,7: Flying * 4: Hovering * 5: Test (?) * 6: Taking off * 8: Landing * 9: Looping (?)
- **rotX**: Left/right tilt in degrees (rotation about the X axis)
- **rotY**: Forward/backward tilt in degrees (rotation about the Y axis)
- **rotZ**: Orientation in degrees (rotation about the Z axis)
- **magX**, magY, magZ: Magnetometer readings (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (TBA: Convention)
- **pressure**: Pressure sensed by Drone's barometer (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (Pa)
- **temp** : Temperature sensed by Drone's sensor (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (TBA: Unit)
- **wind_speed**: Estimated wind speed (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (TBA: Unit)
- **wind_angle**: Estimated wind angle (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (TBA: Unit)
- **wind_comp_angle**: Estimated wind angle compensation (AR-Drone 2.0 Only) (TBA: Unit)
- **altd**: Estimated altitude (mm)
- **motor1**..4: Motor PWM values
- **vx, vy, vz:** Linear velocity (mm/s) [TBA: Convention]
- **ax, ay, az:** Linear acceleration (g) [TBA: Convention]
- **tm**: Timestamp of the data returned by the Drone returned as number of micro-seconds passed since Drone's boot-up.

---

Originally posted by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) with karma: 61 on 2015-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25902/yasser/) on 2016-02-10**:
Hello
what means TBA unit